# Get value of multi-select - No jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, multi-select

Every relevant "question that may already have [my] answer" uses jQuery, which I am not using.

So, is there any simple way to get the values of selected options in a `<select multiple>` tag, or do I have to loop through all the options to see which ones are selected and manually build an array?

Side-question: Which browsers *don't* support `selectElement.value` and instead require `selectElement.options[selectElement.selectedIndex].value`?

Comment: yes you do need to loop from select.selectedIndex to length. I think only very old browsers have issues with .value - I use the second one as defensive coding because there WILL be browsers that don't support it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`select.selectedOptions`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-select-element.html#dom-select-selectedoptions). However, this returns an `HTMLCollection`, so you still have to clean it to get a string array. http://jsfiddle.net/9gd9v/

```
<select multiple>
  <option value="foo" selected>foo</option>
  <option value="bar">bar</option>
  <option value="baz" selected>baz</option>
</select>
```

and:

```
var select = document.querySelector("select");
var values = [].map.call(select.selectedOptions, function(option) {
  return option.value;
});
```

Comment: `selectedOptions` is not x-browser though, no? IE(10) says no to `alert("selectedOptions" in document.createElement("select"));`, and MDN [lists it as not implemented](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLSelectElement). It worked for me in Chrome though...

Comment: Curious why you use `.map()` instead of `.slice()`.

Comment: @Matt: I guessed that. For the cross-browser way, look at the jQuery source and simplify it to your needs.

Comment: @user1689607: No need to create a copy of the array here, you can use `.map` directly.

Comment: @pimvdb: You're creating two new arrays. `[].map` creates and Array, and then it returns a different Array. Same with `.slice()`, but with less code.

Comment: @user1689607: What do you mean? `[].slice.call(...).map(...)` is not really more efficient or cleaner.

Comment: @pimvdb: You're totally right. I misread your code. You do need the callback to get the `.value`. Doh!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLSelectElement, check the selectedOptions

Comment: @xdazz: Yes, if you want full cross browser compatibility without using jQuery, then you *will* have to create some lengthy code.

Comment: @pimvdb It doesn't work in Chrome 21, now it works in Chrome 22, it seems that chrome implement it recently.

Comment: don't use map, use a for loop

Answer (score 0):

If you end up wanting to loop through and grab the selected values you could use something like this:

```
function loopSelected()
{
  var txtSelectedValuesObj = "";
  var selectedArray = new Array();
  var selObj = document.getElementById('selectID');
  var i;
  var count = 0;
  for (i=0; i<selObj.options.length; i++) {
    if (selObj.options[i].selected) {
      selectedArray[count] = selObj.options[i].value;
      count++;
    }
  }
  txtSelectedValuesObj = selectedArray;
  alert(txtSelectedValuesObj);  
}
```

You can view an example **[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/rByjY/1/)**, adapted from **[this example](http://www.mredkj.com/tutorials/tutorial004.html)**.

.

Answer (score 0):

You could also simply track the selected options via the `onchange` event in real-time and collect them whenever you want them. I admit it's still looping, but at least you're not doing it every time you need to retrieve the selected options, and it has the added bonus of being simple (come retrieval time, anyway...). Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cyg9Z/

```
var Test;
if (!Test) {
    Test = {
    };
}
(function () {
    Test.trackSelected = function (e) {
        var selector = document.getElementById('selector'),
            selected = [],
            i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < selector.children.length; i += 1) {
            if (selector.children[i].selected) {
                selected.push(selector.children[i].value)
            }
        }
        selector.selMap = selected;
    };
    Test.addListeners = function () {
        var selector = document.getElementById('selector'),
            tester = document.getElementById('tester');
        selector.onchange = Test.trackSelected;
        tester.onclick = Test.testSelected;
    };
    Test.testSelected = function () {
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.innerText = document.getElementById('selector').selMap.join(', ');
        document.body.appendChild(div);
    };
    Test.addListeners();
}());​
```